# target 'FBSDKLoginKit' has invalid header layout: umbrella header found at

Tags: xcode, facebook-ios-sdk

When compiling my project in the latest version of Xcode I'm running into the following error:

```
Showing Recent Messages
target 'FBSDKLoginKit' has invalid header layout: umbrella header found at '/Users/test/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sumizeit-doqenatycrbstidbqtifkgirkzry/SourcePackages/checkouts/facebook-ios-sdk/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/include/FBSDKLoginKit.h', but directories exist next to it: /Users/test/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sumizeit-doqenatycrbstidbqtifkgirkzry/SourcePackages/checkouts/facebook-ios-sdk/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/include/include; consider removing them
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: anything new on this?